# Method to validate email and alternate email does not accept same emails?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Thank you Guys.. I succeeded it with simple jquery code with calling @onblur = "checkEmail()":

```
function checkEmail() {
                var mainEmail = $('#email').val();
                var altEmail = $('#altEmailTxt').val();
                if(mainEmail==altEmail)
                {
                    $("#emailvalidbox").html("Email and Alternative Email should not be Same");
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#emailvalidbox").html("");
                }
            }
```

Comment: You need to create custom data annotation for that check this link for that : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/mvc-4-custom-validation-data-annotation-attribute/

Comment: The only real way to validate an email address is to send an email to it and confirm that it was received.

Comment: Seems that what you want is creating custom attribute like there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786251/opposite-of-compare-data-annotation-in-net.

Comment: @LaxmanGite : Is there any example with you for this problem. the exmple you provided is for validating email for correct format.

Comment: you can use compare attribute for this. Assuming your primary email id field as 
    public string PrimaryEmail { get; set; }
    [Compare(CompareField = PrimaryEmail)]
    public string SecondaryEmail { get; set; }

Comment: @AmitMishra : it will be validating for equal conditions only, but here i need not equal condition.

Comment: Thank u anyways.. I got the problem resolved by the above answer which i found my own method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go for the custom validation:

**You need to place below line code on the top of your model**

```
 [CompareTwoEmails(ErrorMessage = "Email Id Should be different")]
 public class AddressModel
 {
      public string FirstEmail { get; set; }
      public string SecondEmail { get; set; }
     //Other Properties 
 }
```

**And your custom validation class :**

```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
   public class CompareTwoEmails : ValidationAttribute
   {
       public override bool IsValid(object value)
       {
           var model = (AddressModel)value;
           if (string.Equals(model.FirstEmail, model.SecondEmail, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           {
               return false;

           }
           return true;
       }
   }
```

**Cheers !!**

Comment: Thank u anyways.. I got the problem resolved by the above answer which i found my own methos.